# typescript switch not working with interger input

Tags: typescript

i have a switch like this

```
switch (value){
      case 1 : {
        res = value+"Hirukami Murakmi"
        break;
      }
      case 2 : {
        res = value+"Josephine"
        break;
      }
      default: {
        res = value+"Mikey n Blaky"
        break;
      }
```

it is not working, it always show default value.
i add value just to know the value, and it is correctly define

but if else is working well

```
 if (value == 1) { res = "Hirukami Murakmi"}
    else if (value == 2) { res = "Josephine"}
    else { res = "Mikey n Blaky"}
```

i don't know what is wrong with my switch

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example? In the examples provided, the syntax is off and variables are missing.

Answer (score 1):

When doing with *if/else* statements you are writing double equals (`value == 1`).

The `switch` also compares types, like if you do with triple equals. Therefore it might be that the `value` is and it won't land in the cases, always at default one.

You should cast `value` as a number or do the cases as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the value is not a number, but it is a string. If so, you can do the following:

```
switch (value) {
  case "1": {
    res = value + "Hirukami Murakmi";
    break;
  }
  case "2": {
    res = value + "Josephine";
    break;
  }
  default: {
    res = value + "Mikey n Blaky";
    break;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, this will work if it is truly a number:

```
switch (true) {
  case value == 1: {
    res = value + "Hirukami Murakmi";
    break;
  }
  case value == 2: {
    res = value + "Josephine";
    break;
  }
  default: {
    res = value+"Mikey n Blaky";
    break;
  }
}
```